# Не работает повторное воспроизведение ролика c youtube iframe api на мобильных устройствах

Tags: android, ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-android-api

Здравствуйте,

разработали сайт. На сайт вставили iframe you tube. На компьютере воспроизводится нормально. **На мобильных устройствах: планшетах и телефонах кнопка плей на плеере работает только один раз.** **При повторном нажатии уже не работает.**

С нашей стороны проверили все нормально. Проблема где то в плеере. 
Как решить? 
Спасибо

p.s. Телефоны Android IOS, планшет IOS, браузеры Chrome Safari. Музыка и изображение авторские.

Comment: Боюсь, что дорога вам в Google support. Так как они не слишком давно переехали на html5 плеер и скорее всего, они еще не успели это пофиксить.

Comment: Увы, саппорта как такового у них не существует, есть FAQ, где ,конечно, об этой проблеме ничего нет. Тогда они перенаправляют на некий "любительский" форум. Там я тоже задала вопрос но ни ответа, ни привета, ни даже каких то особых просмотров не получила...